# Receiving runtime error everytime i try to run the code of LeetCode Question Running sum of 1d array

Tags: c

I am trying to solve this LeetCode problem: [Running Sum of 1d Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/running-sum-of-1d-array).

I receive this error:

```c
    solution.c: In function ‘runningSum’
    Line 12: Char 15: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
         tab1[0] = *nums[0];
                   ^~~~~~~~
```

but when I tried to remove the brackets I receive this error:

```c
    Line 207: Char 3: runtime error: load of null pointer of type 'int' (__Serializer__.c)
```

Here's my code:

```c
/**
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */
int* runningSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int* returnSize){

    int tab2[numsSize];

    tab2[0] = *nums[0];
    
    for(int i=1;i<numsSize;i++)
    {
        tab2[i] = *nums[i] + tab2[i-1];
    }
    
    return (tab2);
}
```

Comment: Where is `nums` declared?

Comment: Returning pointer to the local stack memory rarely ends well...

Comment: You are dereferencing `nums` twice. `*nums[0]` should be `nums[0]`

Comment: @EdHeal it's declared in the main which is not available for me

Comment: @Ari0nhh it's my first year in CS in university, yes i studied CS in high school but never was with C, i am sure my algorithm is doing well, i even tried it in my vs code and i am getting what is needed to be. https://prnt.sc/ulhhtx

Comment: @Alaiko when i do like so, i receive another error which is Line 207: Char 3: runtime error: load of null pointer of type 'int' (__Serializer__.c)

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem. That will allow others to test as well.

Comment: The code doesn't do anything with the `returnSize` parameter.

Comment: `[..]` functions as a dereference just as `*` does. So you have `nums` which is type `int*`. `[i]` removes a level of indirection making the type `int`. When you try and use both `*nums[..]` your are removing too many levels of indirection (thus the warning about the unary operator `*`). Remember `*(nums + i)` is equivalent to `nums[i]` and why you can access the first element of `nums` with `*nums` is the equivalent `*(nums + 0)` which is equivalent to `nums[0]`.

Comment: There is a clear working instruction in the comment above the function. You should not just ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Well this code is certainly flawed:

1. You never check function input (for starters, `numsSize` easily could be negative, or zero and it will be bad to declare and use array of such size);
2. You dereference pointer twice, which is an undefined behavior (UB);
3. You return an pointer to the local stack memory, which is UB too;
4. You are not setting up `returnSize` which could break code outside your function call.

Easiest way to solve this problem would be using an input buffer for the output:

```
int* runningSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int* returnSize) {
    if ((numsSize <= 0) || !nums || !returnSize)
        return nums;
    
    for (int i = numsSize-1; i >= 1; --i) {
        nums[i] = nums[i] + nums[i - 1];
    }

    *returnSize = numsSize;
    return nums;
}
```

If using an input buffer is not possible (for example - result shoud be greater size) you should allocate memory dynamically using `malloc` method call.

UPD: Since memory **must** be malloced, you have to allocate memory dynamically:

```
int* runningSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int* returnSize) {
    if ((numsSize <= 0) || !nums || !returnSize)
        return nums;

    *returnSize = numsSize;
    int* ret = malloc(numsSize);
    
    for (int i = 1; i < numsSize; ++i) {
        ret[i] = nums[i] + ret[i - 1];
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help but i even tried your method but this is what i got https://prnt.sc/ulhu8c

Comment: @GhassenJemaî Please next time provide entire problem information. You never tell, that result buffer should be malloced, note in the start of your code clearly says so. I have updated my answer to reflect that

Comment: even wghen i used your last code, i received this error https://prnt.sc/ulhzme

Comment: Yes of course, loop should start from 1, not zero. Fixed that

Comment: thank you again, but that's exactly what i am trying to do https://prnt.sc/um4rkb.